# What was the impact of the Great Recession on the economics curriculum

Tags: macroeconomics

[O. Blanchard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivier_Blanchard) [claims](https://piie.com/blogs/realtime-economic-issues-watch/need-least-five-classes-macro-models#_ftn1) that the discipline needs *at least* 5 types of models. Did the *Great Recession* have an impact on the economics curriculum? What are the discipline areas that were affected/'reformed'? If possible, present a representative example of what got replaced and what took its place.

Comment: I'm guessing that it will take another 5-10 years to sort out any effects.

Comment: Are you asking about the curriculum at a particular level (eg first degree) and in a particular country or group of countries?  Unless you make the question more specific, I think it would be off-topic as too broad.

Comment: @AdamBailey: I wouldn't know at which particular level the curriculum might have been affected; I guess that is the purpose of the question in the first place ie to identify if there has been a change and at what level; (I think that Blanchard in the link covers the whole range from introductory econ to policy making); as far as geography is concerned I guess that the question applies to wherever eg Blachard is relevant

Comment: Consider how long it takes to write a book, especially a technical one.

Comment: @HotLicks if that were the case-I'm not saying that it isn't-then we're talking about some major paradigm shifting changes that would require a complete rewrite of the textbook (introductory, intermediate or advanced). Such changes would leave some residual footprint eg in lecture notes, seminar papers, working papers etc

Comment: Few econ professors are going to change their course materials on their own initiative -- they'll wait for the "authorities" to speak.  The first signs will be some obscure journal articles and likely some "op ed" pieces by the Paul Krugmans, but most instructors would wait for some sort of consensus.